# Rainbow lines in chromebook on using Video capture Card input from mini pc?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, chromebook

Using output from a HP mini PC with Display Port and input into  Chromebook laptop  and a Tobo Video Capture Card HDMI.
Output from mini PC to Video Capture Card via Display Port to HDMI Cable, input into Chromebook from video capture card via USB -UVC.
Default Chromebook Camera app used to view output.

On starting mini PC HP logo appears and starting circle. after that rainbow lines continuously with  no change, but mini pc is running, mouse light is on.

Please help where is the problem ?

[image]